# Query no YII 2 obtendo resultado diferente da clausula Where

Tags: php, yii2

Estou realizando uma consulta, onde contém uma cláusula *where* onde a flag *Status* é que deve ser aplicada durante a execução.

Porém o resultado sempre vem todos, ignorando minha cláusula.

```
Veiculo::find()->select([Veiculo::tableName() . '.id', "CONCAT(descricao, ' - ', placa) AS text"])
            ->innerJoin(ModeloVeiculo::tableName(), ModeloVeiculo::tableName() . '.id = ' . Veiculo::tableName() . '.fk_modelo_veiculo')
            ->where(['<>',Veiculo::tableName() . '.status' ,  4]) 
            ->andWhere(['like', 'placa', $q])
            ->orWhere(['like', 'descricao', $q])->funcaoFilter()->asArray()->all();
```

> ->where(['!=',Veiculo::tableName() . '.status' ,  4]) // Flag para filtrar veiculos com status diferente do tipo 4

Comment: Eu imagino que o código seja PHP, mas, para evitar problemas, seria bom você [edit] o post e adicionar a tag da linguagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorganize seus *where*.

```
  ->where(['like', 'placa', $q])
            ->orWhere(['like', 'descricao', $q])
            ->andWhere(['<>' ,Veiculo::tableName() .'.status' ,  4])->funcaoFilter()->asArray()->all();
```

Havia um erro no momento de checar. O orWhere, estava sobrescrevendo sua clausula, fazendo que o resultado da consulta checassem apenas o OR.